# Tools used to combine individual animation frames into a strip of images

Tags: animation, photoshop

I downloaded a explosion generator that makes an animated explosion but saves each frame as a seperate png image.  I cant for the life of me find a tool that will take all the images and make an animated strip image, with the frames next to each other.  I tried gimp but no luck!  The Photoshop image combiner is too cumbersome.  Any recommended utilites to do this?

Comment: ok, so imagemagick seems pretty good.  Anyone have other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Gimp can do this, and it is actually a piece of cake.

Open all the frames as individual images. Then on the first image select `Filters|Combine|Film Strip`. Add the remaining frames to the list on the right side (in the correct order).

Now click on the `Advanced` tab and set Image Height all the way to the right (1.000) and Image spacing all the way to the left (0.000).

Hit OK and you should have your filmstrip!

Answer (score -1):

The GIMP film strip works fine but does force a background color on you, if you have images with transparent (alpha) background this might be problematic for you.

Comment: this should be a comment instead of an answer.